# Difficulty installing a CNC pendant linuxcnc

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I am only familiar enough with Linux to run my CNC software with it.

I am attempting to install the software for a Imach M1 CNC pendant. [www.vistacnc.com](http://www.vistacnc.com)

The problem I am running into is with the following instructions -

1. Copy and move following files to LinuxCNC PC
   Makefile
   vc-m1
   vc-m1.hal
   99-vistacnc-pendant.rules
2. Put Makefile, vc-m1 and 99-vistacnc-pendant.rules to “src” under home directory ~/src$. If there is a Makefile in that directory, name that make file to different name, like Makefile_old.
3. Run make install , this will install vc-m1 to /usr/bin and 99-vistacnc-pendant.rules to /lib/udev/rules.d

I can not find the SRC location they want me to put these files in. I have found an SRC Folder that has several other folders in it. I am unfamiliar with how to navigate, so If anyone tries to respond to me, please treat me like a not very bright child. Runing oldish Ubuntu on a really old thinkpad t30. Any help would make my day.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1):

'`~`' means your home directory, so `~/src` means `/home/your_username/src`.

You are correct: That directory is not created by Ubuntu.

However, there is nothing magical about that directory. You can create it and destroy it as much as you wish without harming your system.

Create the directory using either your file manager or terminal (`mkdir ~/src`).

Comment: Thanks for that. I talked to a friend who walked me through setting all this up in terminal. Still no joy, but I suspect that is another issue.